# Derivative map on line bundles of $ \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derivatives, complex-geometry

The function field $K(\mathbb{P}^1)$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is given by rational functions homogeneous in $x, y$ of total degree $0$. The picard group of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and we can take as representatives of the isomorphism classes of line bundles in $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ the bundles $\mathcal{O}(nP)$ where $P=[1:0] \in \mathbb{P}^1$. Then the sections of $\mathcal{O}(nP)$ on the distinguished open $U_f$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$ for $f$ some degree $d$ homogeneous polynomial in $x, y$ are given by $\frac{p}{y^nf^k} \in K(\mathbb{P}^1)$ so that $p$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n+dk$.

Now, given a section  of $\mathcal{O}(nP)(U_f)$ one can differentiate with respect to $\frac{x}{y}$ and get some element of $\mathcal{O}((n-1)P)(U_f)$ (here I'm temporarily thinking of the function field as rational functions (not necessarily homogeneous) in $\frac{x}{y}$).

So the upshot is that we get a map $D: \mathcal{O}(n) \to \mathcal{O}(n-1)$. This is not a map of line bundles but does satisfy the property $D(\alpha g)=D(\alpha)g + \alpha D(g)$ for $g \in \mathcal{O}(n)(U_f), \alpha \in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Thus, it's some sort of derivation between line bundles.

Now the question. I'd like to generalize this map to more interesting varieties than $\mathbb{P}^1$. How do I do this? Any more general context for these maps would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Can one think of this derivative map as some sort of derivation of sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1$ and if so, how?

Comment: Notice that «taking derivatives with respect to one of the variables» is not something that makes sense, because there are no variables: neither P^1 nor your line bundles have any preferred choice of charts.

Comment: I suggest you ask the question in the question body :-)

Comment: So I guess one would have to fix coordinates first?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Hi Mariano, I totally rewrote the question. Is it clearer what I'm interested in?

Comment: The canonical derivation is from $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)=\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}$, the De Rham map. This generalizes to all varieties over any field, to get  the De Rham complex.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, but now I want to consider "derivations" where the source is a line bundle.

Comment: There is a notion of connection in algebraic geometry and there's quite a bit of literature on it. Is that the sort of thing you want?

Comment: @Hoot Yeah, that is the sort of thing. I'd imagine that one can write down a connection $\mathcal{O}(n) \to \mathcal{O}(n) \otimes \Omega$ and then the maps $\mathcal{O}(n) \to \mathcal{O}(n-1)$ I constructed would factor through this. But I  haven't managed to get it to work yet.